# Tell Apache to ignore content-length in HTTP Header

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is this possible to tell apache either in **vhost** or in **.htaccess** to ignore content-length in **HTTP POST Header** in a **multipart request**? We have a API in Lumen that cannot work properly because the content-length from Ruby cannot be set properly with both parameters and files set ... (I don't know Ruby ... )

Comment: This should really rather be fixed on the ruby side ... // If this is your actual API code and not the web server itself that has a problem with those requests, then having Apache “ignore” the header won’t do much - but you could tell Apache to _unset_ it, via the `RequestHeader` directive.

Comment: I am using PHP, the client is using Ruby, and they cannot figure it out ... so we sort of have to hack thru the problem ...